The bottom bar is hidden behind system navigation icons when enabling Edge to Edge in Compose
I'm trying to change status and navigation bar styles using enableEdgeToEdge(), but the custom bottom bar became hidden behind the system navigation buttons, as in the attached image. If anyone knows what is wrong with this code.

LaunchedEffect(dark) {
    if (!dark) {
        enableEdgeToEdge(
            statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
                Color.White.toArgb(), Color.White.toArgb(),
            ),
            navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
                Color.White.toArgb(), Color.White.toArgb(),
            ),
        )
    } else {
        enableEdgeToEdge(
            statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.dark(
                Color.Blue.toArgb(),
            ),
            navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.dark(
                Color.Blue.toArgb(),
            ),
        )
    }
}

Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController) }
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
            HomeNavGraph(
                navController = navController,
                selectedTheme = selectedTheme,
                onItemSelected = onItemSelected,
                userData = userData,
                signOut = { signOut() },
                locale = locale, country = country, q = q
            )
        }
    }


Your code is correct and this is correct behavior since you want edgeToEdge, just use Modifier.navigationBarsPadding() for your BottomBar to make it appear as you want like this:
Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { 
           BottomBar(
              navController = navController,
              //Don't forget to apply the modifier inside your BottomBar composable
              modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()
           ) 
        }
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
            HomeNavGraph(
                navController = navController,
                selectedTheme = selectedTheme,
                onItemSelected = onItemSelected,
                userData = userData,
                signOut = { signOut() },
                locale = locale, country = country, q = q
            )
        }
    }


Unfortunately, it is still in the same state. It's working with the method activity.window.statusBarColor, but only in light mode.

@ArthurThuma Can you show how did you applied the Modifier in your BottomBar? For me it's working fine when placing .navigationBarsPadding() as first modifier.

@Composable
fun BottomBar(
modifier: Modifier,
navController: NavHostController
) { // }
Scaffold(
topBar = {},
bottomBar = {
BottomBar(
modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsPadding(),
navController = navController
)
}
) {  // }

@ArthurThuma This is fine but i mean if you really applied the modifier inside BottomBar composable. One thing is adding the parametr and another one is using it, can you show?

Yes, I didn't use it inside the BottomBar composable, so it is working now, but it's not updated in dark mode.

@ArthurThuma Honestly not sure what to recommend now. I created just simple example based on your code  and it's working fine for both light/dark mode. Maybe try to debug it if there is some bug or like theme dependent code. But i am pretty sure that navigationBarsPadding() modifier  is working fine, using it for long time.

Sure, I will try. You've already given a good answer.
